# Phrase / idiom for a rising after a temporary comedown

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

How can one idiomatically or by using a phrase refer to a situation of something rising (e.g. a disease, pandemic, recession) after a temporary comedown?

Comment: The word which fits best will depend on the specific context.  Do you have a scenario in mind?

Comment: @mjjf, for example, a new wave of an outbreak after some improvements (in a country-wide scale).

Answer (score 13):

To rebound or bounce back would be a good fit in a business context. https://hbr.org/2010/03/are-you-ready-to-rebound

Comment: Yeah, "bounce back" would be appropriate in many contexts.

Answer (score 11):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/resurgence) has

> **resurgence**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> An increase or revival after a period of little activity, popularity, or occurrence.

Some examples given are

> *It is also used as a mosquito repellant, a significant contribution in a region where the resurgence of malaria is responsible for thousands of deaths.*
>
> *Indeed, we now know that, far from being a ‘dark age’, this period saw an economic resurgence in Anglo-Saxon England.*

So this fits all the use cases given.

Answer (score 3):

You might be talking about a "recurrence", "flare-up", or "recrudescence" (though those words wouldn't work well with "recession"). If you put those into a thesaurus you'll get other synonyms, too.

Comment: *Flare-up* is a good noun for this.

Comment: Recrudescence is a word I've never heard before as a relatively well versed native speaker. It definitely fits, but the others are much more likely to be understood. Thanks for the $10 word today @MarcInManhattan

Answer (score 2):

**Relapse**

from [Oxford Languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en)

*verb*

(of someone suffering from a disease) suffer deterioration after a period of improvement.

*noun*

a deterioration in someone's state of health after a temporary improvement.

Comment: That's the opposite

Comment: @alex_danielssen While the phrasing may be confusing, I believe the OP wanted something specifically about something getting worse after a temporary reprieve.  My understanding of that comes from the examples they used in reference to "rising".  Each of those are things that are worse when rising and better when coming down.   Without those examples, I would agree that this seem to ask about getting worse before getting better, but with those, I believe this word fits.

Comment: OTOH, relapse is mostly used for diseases. It could be used metaphorically for other bad situations, but I don't think it's common. And individual can have a COVID relapse, but I've never heard anyone call widespread resurgences as relapses.

Comment: The question was something rising after lowering.  The connotations of 'relapse' refer to the health of the patient rather than the prevalence of the disease. In this case, the health lowers after rising.  Even though we might say that the disease or condition rises after lowering in a relapse, the word doesn't refer to the disease itself.

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of a ***comedown***?

[merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/come%20down) says:

| **Antonyms for comedown** | **Near Antonyms for comedown** |
| --- | --- |
| aggrandizement ascent exaltation rise up shape up spring up | advance headway progress flower heyday prime |

...but the first word that came to me was "comeback".

**come·back**
*/kŭm′băk′/*

1. to become healthy and strong again after illness or weakness.
   *she's slowly coming back after being in a coma*
2. to regain a former or normal state.
   *the American bald eagle was once nearly extinct but has come back strong*

Answer (score 1):

Very irreverent and colloquial, but "second wind" is one used frequently in the UK.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=second+wind

Comment: Why is it *Very irreverent and colloquial*?

Answer (score 0):

Tick-tock

Swung back

Doubled back

Resiled

Bobbed-up

Recommenced

Restarted

Rekindled

Reignited

Renewed

Regained

Reinstituted (generally used in 3rd person)

Restituted (generally used in 3rd person, also is a monetary term)

Reanimated